# Chrome driver crashing on launch in linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, selenium, google-chrome

```
package webapp;

//import java.sql.Driver;
//import java.util.*;

//import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/ajay/Documents/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        
//System.out.println("Hlinux"
        //+"ello");
    }




    }
```

Hi, I am working on selenium webdriver on linux in  eclipse the chrome driver starts but crashes immediately please have a look.

Comment: Does it have any error message?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed. (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'ajay-System-Product-Name', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-52-generic', java.version: '11.0.8'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
remote stacktrace: #0 0x55d180755d99 <unknown>

Comment: So can you run the process located at `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` outside of your app?

Comment: yes the browser launches successfully

Answer (score 2):

`chromedriver.exe` is the executable for Windows OS. It won't be running on Linux. Download appropriate driver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=87.0.4280.20/).

Make also sure that the file you have downloaded has the appropriate execution permission set.

Comment: Still  same issue

Comment: Can you amend your question? What exactly have you changed?

Comment: I have changed chromedriver.exe to chromedriver but still getting error as chromedriver crashed

Comment: @QualityAssuranceEngineer Your question still says otherwise. Edit your question to improve it. Include the error message also into the question, not as comment. If the comments in the code have no meaning, delete them.